# No backend styling in OctoberCMS after deploying on IIS

Tags: laravel, iis, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm having a problem with the backend when I deploy my site to the IIS of my web host, it has no styling. At first I had this problem with my entire site but then I added the IIS configuration code from the documentation to my web.config file in the root map and it fixed the front-end but the backend is still broken. I can still login but there is just no styling, it's a bit difficult to navigate the backend that way ;)

Here is some more info:

- PHP version 7.0.19
- October system build 419
- IIS webserver

[This is how my backend login screen look right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ya0j.png)

I added some other code snippets that I found on the internet to my web.config file but that didn't solve the problem. Has anyone encountered the same problem? If so, could you tell me what might fix this?

Edit: [Chrome Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksrjy.png)

Comment: Can you please screenshoot the network tab on chrome console? I think you need to see all the url of loaded assets.

Comment: Sure, I added the screenshot to the the post.

Answer (score 1):

To deploying your octobercms to server, you need to change the `url` parameter in `config/app.php` file. It's should look like this:

`'url' => 'http://yourdomain.com/',`

Don't forget it should contain `http://` or `https://` string.

Hope it helps